# WebKit shell browser for internal web application

Tags: xcode, browser, webkit

I am creating an in-house web application that I want to run in a WebKit shell browser on the Mac. I searched and came up empty. Basically, I want the site rendered and shown in a window with no chrome for navigating to other pages, bookmarks, etc. Seems to me that there should be a relatively easy way to get something like that up and running in Xcode, but alas I don't know how. The more barebones the better. Anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could use a [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  The content is rendered by Safari/WebKit.

As for chrome, if you just put the view, that's all you'll have.  You can shape the rest of the User Interface however you'd like.

Apple's documentation has a couple of examples using WebView... Should this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the phonegap mac project.

Its a full screen webkit without any chrome in which you can put your html / css / javascript to run:

https://github.com/callback/callback-mac